# Properly align vertex labels (decorated with brace) of different lengths in tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

In the following (incomplete) Feynman diagram,

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
      \vertex (i1) {$b$};
      \vertex [right=of i1] (m1) ;
      \vertex [right=of m1] (o1) {$c$};
      \vertex [below=2em of i1] (i2) {$\bar u, \bar d$};
      \vertex [right=of i2] (m2) ;
      \vertex [right=of m2] (o2) {$\bar u, \bar d$};

      \diagram* {
        (i1) -- [fermion] (m1),
        (m1) -- [fermion] (o1),
        (o2) -- [fermion] (m2),
        (m2) -- [fermion] (i2)
      };
      
      % annotations
      \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i2.south west) -- (i1.north west)
        node [pos=0.5, left] {$B^-, \bar B^{0}$};
    \end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the bracket is drawn at an angle

[image]

because the labels have different lengths. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By use of the orthogonal coordinate `(i2.west |- i1.north)` for top side of brace:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
  \vertex (i1) {$b$};
  \vertex [right=of i1] (m1) ;
  \vertex [right=of m1] (o1) {$c$};
  \vertex [below=2em of i1] (i2) {$\bar{u}, \bar d$};
  \vertex [right=of i2] (m2) ;
  \vertex [right=of m2] (o2) {$\bar{u}, \bar{d}$};

  \diagram* {
    (i1) -- [fermion] (m1),
    (m1) -- [fermion] (o1),
    (o2) -- [fermion] (m2),
    (m2) -- [fermion] (i2)
            };
% annotations
  \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] 
    (i2.south west) -- node [left] {$B^-, \bar{B}^{0}$} (i2.west |- i1.north);
\end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. But is my curly bracket vertical? :-( or is it the effect of TeXworks?

Comment: @Sebastiano, as far as I see, both are vertical (and this is independent from used editor) :-).  (+1 for your solution)

Comment: Zarko....I have put immediately the upvote. ahhaha. But do you have tried to compile my code? See if it is the same of your curly bracket.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I tested and frankly said, your brace is almost vertical. Discrepancy arise because the width of the label `$ b \ hphantom {, \ bar d}` is slightly smaller than width of the label $\ bar u, \ bar d $`, but  it is almost negligibly small.

Comment: Thank you very much for all and for your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

Putting just a phantom `\hphantom{,\bar d}` on `\vertex (i1)` the problem is solved. The length of the fermions are also the same.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
      \vertex (i1) {$b\hphantom{,\bar d}$};
      \vertex [right=of i1] (m1) ;
      \vertex [right=of m1] (o1) {$c$};
      \vertex [below=2em of i1] (i2) {$\bar u, \bar d$};
      \vertex [right=of i2] (m2) ;
      \vertex [right=of m2] (o2) {$\bar u, \bar d$};

      \diagram* {
        (i1) -- [fermion] (m1),
        (m1) -- [fermion] (o1),
        (o2) -- [fermion] (m2),
        (m2) -- [fermion] (i2)
      };
      % annotations
      \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (i2.south west) -- (i1.north west)
        node [pos=0.5, left] {$B^{-}, \bar B^{0}$};
    \end{feynman}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this at first but wasn't satisfied with the result (for which Zarko has given the reason.)